# Spring Cloud Eureka with Python Django client

Tags: django, spring, python-3.x, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Can we discover python Django micro service from spring Eureka registry (without using Site car or any java library)?

I tried this also but I haven't got any success yet.

```
from eureka.client import EurekaClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

ec = EurekaClient("MyApplication",eureka_domain_name="python_client",region="127.0.0.1",
                  vip_address="http://192.168.120.14:8761/eureka",port=8761, )

print ec.get_zones_from_dns()
print ec.get_eureka_urls()
print ec.register()
print ec.update_status("UP")  # Or ec.register("UP")
print ec.heartbeat()
```

Comment: Should theoretically be possible. eureka is just an http API. I'm not familiar with a python eureka client so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are trying to add your python-microservice in spring-boot framework.
Eureka client should discover your service .
please check if you have updated the bootstrap.properties file with entry like:

```
spring.application.name=EmployeeEurekaServer
```

`eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://localhost:8761/`

```
`server.port=8761`
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

This will allow your application on the Eureka-Guestlist.
Hope this answers!!